# Android Studio 3.0 - No server to serve request

Tags: android-studio

After clean install of Android Studio I always get the error

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for
>   details.

and

> Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

Java is up to date and the path is set.

I am new to Android Studio, what should I try?

Answer (score 14):

We ran into the same issue, and have been able to find the root cause: The error message means that Gradle cannot connect to some worker processes. In our case, the process was for 'aapt2'. Running 'ldd aapt2' indicated that some shared libraries were missing (mainly GLIBC). Since we're using Docker based on Alpine Linux, it comes with a reduced GLIBC (glibc-musl). The solution was to simply install glibc in the Docker container.

I suggest you run `ldd build-tools/{version}/aapt2`
to see which libraries are missing from the OS. You did not mention your OS, are you also using Docker and AlpineLinux ?

Comment: for osx, it is:
otool -L build-tools/{version}/aapt2

Comment: I ran the command on my Macbook, @blagerweij how do you know which libraries are missed?

Comment: otool (and ldd) will display the missing libraries. You can also try to run the command from the console to see if it's corrupted. Run 'aapt2 compile -h' for instance

Comment: I run the following command `otool -L build-tools/27.0.3/aapt` and got this result `build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2:
 @rpath/libc++.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)` what next? I use docker image

Comment: How did you find the root cause / process that was causing this issue (on linux)?

Comment: First we ran the gradle build in verbose mode (--info or --debug), which indicated that there was a problem in running the 'aapt2' command. When we inspected the binary, it turns out that 'aapt2' is dynamically linked, which means that it depends on external libraries. In our case, some libs were missing (glibc). After installing glibc the problem was resolved. Please have a look at our Dockerfile for reference: https://github.com/blagerweij/android-builder/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I did not need to re-download the sdk. I closed Android Studio and ran the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R ~/Desktop/AndroidStudio
```

...where, ~/Desktop/AndroidStudio was the folder structure after Root which I needed to mention in order to provide permission to read all the SDK packages and perform required operation as and when necessary by the Android Studio, because my Sdk folder was inside "~/Desktop/AndroidStudio".

I am running Android Studio 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This worked for me perfectly :-)

Comment: Its also work for Ubuntu 18.04 and Android studio 3.1.4.  Thank you.

Comment: for Mac OS `sudo chmod -R 777 $ANDROID_HOME`

Answer (score 4):

This error occurred because you might have accidentally remove the executable flag from `aapt2` which is located in `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/27.0.2`.

Try this:

- Re-download the sdk (recommended)

followed by-

- `sudo chmod 777 -R $ANDROID_HOME`

**Note:**
`$ANDROID_HOME` is the location where I put android sdk

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 2):

Had to uninstall Android studio and delete the following 
SDK folder in AppData folder 
Delete .gradle folder 
delete .AndroidStudio Projects folder

and did a fresh install which solved .

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on lubuntu-16 32bit (and also some other problems too). all of the problems were solved when I updated my system to lubuntu-16 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here how I fixed this Issue:

1.Deleted .gradle folder.

2.Closed android studio and run as administrator.

On Start android studio will rebuild the folder you deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo chmod 777 -R $ANDROID_HOME

Note: **$ANDROID_HOME** is the location where you put android sdk

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you, please delete the build folder of project and test building android project with any other version of build-tools.

in my case, build-tools version: 26.0.2 had problem, I tested with 27.0.3 and it solved my problem unbelievably :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and it turned out I had messed up the file permissions inside the android-sdk folder (more specifically android-sdk/build-tools/{version}), and some binaries were missing execution permissions.

In my case, I simply gave `x` permissions to the relevant files in that directory, but if you're not sure, I suggest you uninstall the android sdk, completely remove its directory and then reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

So after investigating the issue for long , I have a concrete solution .
Let`s look into it.

Go to **Android Studio -> Help -> Show Log In Files**

In the subsequent folder that opens, open **idea.log**

This would present you with a log file which contains logs of processes right from when the studio started. Now in this file, you have to search for the possible issue. For some the issue might be due to

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/mmt/Android-Sdk/android-sdk-linux_x86/emulator/emulator-check": error=13, Permission denied

For some others, it may be some other. The point is that this file contains lot of irrelevant logs and you have to identify the one that is causing this issue. For me , after discovering the above issue, I granted permission to that particular folder using the below commands

> cd $ANDROID_HOME/sudo chmod -R 777 emulator/

After this, rebuild your project and tadaaa.. problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a virus that corrupted my files from the "build tools" folder. so I uninstalled everything and made a new installation of android studio, SDK and build tools.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is the side effect of another issue that I haven't root caused yet. Every once in a while, I get aapt2 failures because some file `/tmp/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is "busy", with the following error message.

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1745790725): cp: cannot create regular file '/tmp/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': Text file busy
Slave 1745790725 failed to start java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at ~/.../android-sdk-linux/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2) are not corrupted.
```

When this happens I just rm that file and everything starts working again. I suspect this might be caused by me actually having two installs of adb (one through ubuntu via apt and one from Android studio) but I haven't had time to dive deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I already had latest version of `build-tool` installed, so I just had to  give permission to Android_home:

```
chmod 777 -R $ANDROID_HOME
```

and build again. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows 10 (sigh), close android studio and then right click on android studio icon and select 'Run as Administrator' from 'more' menu.

Build again.

Answer (score -2):

You can run Android Studio as Admin.

I hope it will help you.

To Do So :

1. Right click
2. choose Run as Administrator

Best regards,