# How can I fix out Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request

Tags: java, android

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
> Information:BUILD FAILED in 2s
> Information:2 errors
> Information:0 warnings
> Information:See complete output in console

I also go through link but did not get solution: this [Android Studio 3.0 - No server to serve request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113665/android-studio-3-0-no-server-to-serve-request)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Need an answer urgently.

Answer (score -1):

"Tested on Ubuntu® 14.04 LTS, Trusty Tahr (64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications)
64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications"

Your machine has to be a 64 bit if you're using Linux.
Also have the same problem on my 32 bit laptop but works fine on my 64 bit laptop.