# No server to serve request

Tags: java, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to build a new fresh project in Android Studio 3.0.1 with Java 1.8.0_151-b12. My computer is running Ubuntu 16.04.3. I get the following errors:

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

I realize there is already this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113665/android-studio-3-0-no-server-to-serve-request), but the suggested solutions did not resolve the errors.

I have tried all suggested fixes such as `ldd Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2` and get the result `not a dynamic executable`. I removed and re-downloaded the SDK twice. I ran `chmod -R 777 Android/`. I haven't tried a reinstall of Android Studio yet but that is next on my things to try. Any other solutions? Thanks.

Edit:
Did a reinstall of Android Studio and still have same error.

Comment: Try just running "$ Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2 m" (which is exactly the command used by studio to start the aapt2 daemon process) and paste the output here. You're probably missing some libraries and the error given from this command should shed some light on the issue (it should be also present in the gradle log).

Comment: $ Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2 m
bash: Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: So the executable cannot be run. Check if your firewall isn't blocking it?

Comment: I didn't know that Android Studio required internet connection to run? But, Android Studio runs fine on another computer that has Windows 7. So I don't think it is a firewall problem.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant that your antivirus might be blocking this executable since even if you run it from command line it doesn't work. Are you using 32 bit windows?

Comment: No, Ubuntu 16.04.3. No anti-virus.