# Jenkins CI Android Gradle Build Fail

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I have use `jenkins with docker`
after pull and install the following plugin

1. Git Plugin
2. Gradle Plugin
3. Android Lint Plugin
4. Google Play Android Publisher Plugin

**THEN** setup JDK, Repository (GitLab)

**AND** create project and run, it's show the following error.

## RUN COMMAND

docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk:/var/android_home -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts

## JENKINS CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ABC Project
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://office.viinsoft.com/issoft/mappening-android.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://office.viinsoft.com/issoft/mappening-android.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress http://office.viinsoft.com/issoft/mappening-android.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 7a760b63852e92c57e5b4dea5bdf6680b01d8894 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 7a760b63852e92c57e5b4dea5bdf6680b01d8894
Commit message: "Test Jenkins#2"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 7a760b63852e92c57e5b4dea5bdf6680b01d8894 # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[Mappening Project] $ "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/gradlew" assembleDebug
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDevDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 849578689): /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 6: /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
AAPT err(Facade for 1702555035): /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 6: /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Slave 1702555035 failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2) are not corrupted.
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 1365735589): /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 6: /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Slave 1365735589 failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2) are not corrupted.
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 212997924): /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 6: /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Slave 212997924 failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2) are not corrupted.
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Slave 849578689 failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2) are not corrupted.
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:211)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
:app:mergeDevDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
7 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 6 up-to-date
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

## TRAIL AND STILL ERROR

I was google around it seem that, a solution need to use older build-tool which I don't want [Android studio 2.1.2 gradle aapt Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663495/android-studio-2-1-2-gradle-aapt-syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string/39687455)

and someone said I have missing library to execute 64 bit code, so I run the following command on my mac OSX and check, but it seem okay [Android Studio 3.0 - No server to serve request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113665/android-studio-3-0-no-server-to-serve-request)

```
otool -L build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2
build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2:
    @rpath/libc++.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

finally, I give permission to my local path  `sudo chmod 755 -R /Users/sattha.p/Library/Android/sdk` but nothing change even restart docker.

Comment: `/var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: 6: /var/android_home/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` I think it's reason.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Yes, but I don't know the root cause of this error exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663495/android-studio-2-1-2-gradle-aapt-syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string
Please check it

Comment: I think, I already provide this link in the question... thank you anyway @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: Oh yes. I'm so sorry. I only have experience with Jenkins iOS.

Comment: still, cannot found a solution, so bad T.T