# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

Tags: java, android

Actually for this problem I got some solution in stack overflow .But none of them works . 
In some post , they informed that the problem is due to 32 bit operating system and suggest to upgrade the operating system.

When some said that it is due to platform tools. Updated version causes problem with 32 bit OS .

So  I implemented all of their solution ! But Can not resolve the problem .
Anyone please explain the actual solution .

> null
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No > server to serve request. Check logs for details.

Comment: Could you share your logs? Also have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113665/android-studio-3-0-no-server-to-serve-request

Comment: I tried these solutions but none these works :(

Comment: Please share your logs

Comment: Actually I am new to android and I find log only in   "help menu ->show log in file "
Which have bigger file .. So I did not get  which log you want ! Can you pease tell me where to find it ??

Comment: Check Toolbar -> Help Menu -> Show log in explorer. Then try to attach the log here (Not sure if file size limit is there in stackoverflow)