# Java compiler error while building in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using android studio 3.1.3, and gradle version 4.4. I'm a beginner to android development but I can't seem to be able to get android studio to build successfully. I get a Java compiler error stating: "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details. ".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 - No server to serve request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113665/android-studio-3-0-no-server-to-serve-request)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when android studio couldn't connect to aapt2(possibly you deleted it)

One Solution would be is to close the android studio, delete the .gradle folder in your project. then start the android studio as an administrator or with sudo incase of linux.

2.2nd Solution
Other would be is to redownload the SDK 
then

```
sudo chmod 777 -R $ANDROID_HOME
```

Where $ANDROID_HOME is the location of SDK

Comment: OP didn't mention he's using Linux based OS. So, using `sudo` command in non Linux systems doesn't make sense. :)